# Unable to access Menu item values - wrapped in a V7 MenuItemWrapperJB

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionmode

So I have been googleing for weeks and I cant figure out why my menu items are wrapped in a wrapper object that means I am unable to access values such as item id though the menuItem.getItemId method. What really confuses me is that I previously was using a floating contextual menu and it worked fine.

This is the code I use to access the item id.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.submit: ...
```

The exact type of object it gives me is: android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemWrapperJB

All the subsequent crashes are to do with me querying my SQLite DB with the id if the menu item but calling the getMenuId method returns a number like 2131558592.

edit - My question is why is this wrapper object here and how can I get the object I want to access , namely the item, out of it.

edit 2 - Ok so what had me confused was the fact that the wrapper wasn't there when I was using a floating context menu. The real issue is that I am unable to use item.getMenuInfo to get the id of the selected item in my list view with the wrapper whereas I was able to before(With the floating context menu).

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: *getMenuId method returns a number like 2131558592* and? 2131558592 is prolly value of `R.id.submit`

Comment: OK maybe that part is irrelevant but how can I get the object I need out of the wrapper and why is it there in the first place, maybe I should have been clearer about my question

Comment: wrapped and so what? why you bother about this(implementation)? MenuItem is an interface ...

Answer (score 2):

> I am unable to access values such as item id though the menuItem.getItemId method

Sure you are. Otherwise, your code would not compile.

> The exact type of object it gives me is: android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemWrapperJB

That is because you are using `appcompat-v7`, though it would not appear to be relevant to your problem.

> All the subsequent crashes are to do with me querying my SQLite DB with the id if the menu item

If you are creating your menu items directly in Java code, what you are describing is not completely insane. If, however, you are defining your menu items through menu resources, the `R.id` values are generated. Those values will change from build to build, as you change the mix of resources in your app. Persisting those values, such as in a database, is not going to work reliably.

> how can I get the object I need out of the wrapper

You don't. `MenuItem` is an interface; you call methods on the interface, regardless of its underlying implementation. Technically, you don't know that it is a wrapper in the first place, though the class name certainly suggests it.

> why is it there in the first place

If you inflated a menu resource, the `appcompat-v7` edition of the `MenuInflater` probably substituted its own implementation of `MenuItem`, as part of the backported action bar support.

If you created the `MenuItem` in Java code, through calls to `add()` or something on `Menu`, the `appcompat-v7` edition of `Menu` created an `appcompat-v7` edition of a `MenuItem`.

Comment: Ok I'm beginning to see the issue. Seems like horrible logic errors on my part. Thanks for being so clear!

Comment: So I'm not sure if you would be notified of my many edits but you are the man to ask so, I am unable to use the item.getMenuInfo method to access  the ID of the selected item in the list view because it returns null. Is there a different method to use to access the ID when using support v7 business?

Comment: @Jack.Ramsden: "I am unable to use the item.getMenuInfo method to access the ID of the selected item in the list view because it returns null" -- gosh, I haven't seen `getMenuInfo()` used in *years*. I'm not aware that it works with action modes in general, let alone specifically in `onActionItemClicked()`, if that's where you are trying to call it.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm just using the wrong method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Right way to cast View in AppCompat library:

for example casting a search view

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
```

So you need to cast you submit view. hope it helps